# Deploying iphone apps on device for testing purpose

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want my peers or family friends to test my apps for feedback before I deploy it on appstore. Is there some way that I could install it directly from my machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just register each device you want in [Apple's iPhone Dev site](http://developer.apple.com) and generate a provisioning profile including all devices you would like to test on.

After that, plug each device to your Mac, open Organizer in XCODE, and just run the application in **device mode**. Application will be installed on the iPhone, and you can freely test it for a couple of months. After that, provisioning profile will expire and you will have to generate a new one, install the application again, and start the process over.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to join iPhone development program which costs $99 per year. Once you joined that you can create development certificates and provisioning profiles to digitally sign your application. It is necessary to sign an application before it can be deployed to a device.

Answer (score 0):

You can register up to 100 device UDIDs with Apple's $99 Individual iOS Developer Program, and install apps on any or all of those devices either by debug USB tethering to your development Mac, or by AdHoc installation via iTunes on their computers (PC or Mac).