# beta-testing an app with PUSH APNS

Tags: ios, push, distribution, apple-push-notifications, beta-testing

I'm developing an app which uses APNS and I would like to distribute it for betatesting to some close friends. This is the first app I build and will be the first time distributing an app.

Well. To test it in my iPhone I had to make a provisioning profile and install a certificate in my iPhone. How can I send my app by email (or smth) and then install it easily without have to put manually the certificate in their iPhones? Which steps should I follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of question gets asked often here ([and here is another question with answers you might find useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553206/deploying-iphone-apps-on-device-for-testing-purpose)).

I've heard good things about [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com). [Here is an article describing the service](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2011/01/21/testflight-iphone-app-testing-over-the-air/).  I hope my answer helps you out!

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. First option is not possible, I do not have face-to-face contact with some of them and, secondly, using APNS requires a certificate which I don't know how to distribute.

Comment: Well APNS is an entirely separate and mutually exclusive question ("how do I set up push notifications") from the main question that you have ("how to distribute beta test apps"). If you set up push notifications for your app and it works for your device, it'll work for distributed test apps to your friends.  The things you need to pass along for testing are a provisioning profile and an .ipa file.

Comment: I know that the app will work. So, what should I do first? Add every device to the provisioning portal and then download the provisioning profile? How do I get my friends' ID or add their devices to the provisioning? Thanks!

Comment: That's yet another set of questions (and all easily Googleable).  [Here is how to get device UUID's](http://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid) and [here is how to add device to provisioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578158/adding-devices-to-team-provisioning-profile).

Comment: Ok Michael, the first one was perfect. Alright, then, once I have all devices registered in the provisioning profile, what should I do? Download it and send them (.ipa and the file) to my friends? What should they do with that two files to get the app working? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app I hope it works when I try it. Thanks Michael!